# How to add controls to a Delphi TFlowLayout dynamically

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can I add controls to a TFlowLayout at runtime? Setting the Parent is enough for a TLayout but doesn't seem to work for a TFlowLayout. This code expalins my issue:

```
procedure AddLabel;
var
  LLabel: TLabel;
begin
  LLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  LLabel.Parent := Layout1;  // LABEL SHOWS OK
  LLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  LLabel.Parent := FlowLayout1;  // LABEL DOESN'T SHOW
end;
```

If I do this, I get an AV:

```
procedure AddLabel;
var
  LLabel: TLabel;
begin
  LLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FlowLayout1.Controls.Add(LLabel);  // THROWS AV
end;
```

I know GridPanel has RowCollections & ColumnCollections, but what's up with TFlowLayout I do not know.

Comment: Usually use `AddObject()` for this, so `FlowLayout1.AddObject(LLabel);`.

Answer (score 0):

Code bellow works fine on 10.4. In your case label may be not show because there is no text assigned to **Text** property. When you drop TLabel to form design time IDE auto assign text to him.

I tested without assigning text to caption and voila label is not here anymore.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    flwlytMain: TFlowLayout;
    btnStart: TButton;
    procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyLabel: TLabel;
  MyButton : TButton;
  ControlList: TControlList;
begin
  MyLabel := TLabel.create(self);
  MyLabel.Parent := flwlytMain  ;
  MyLabel.AutoSize := true;
  MyLabel.Text := 'Test   ';
  MyLabel.Font.Size := 48;
  MyLabel.Visible := True;
  MyButton := TButton.Create(self);
  MyButton.Text := 'Another test';
  MyButton.Width := 120;
  MyButton.parent := flwlytMain;
  MyButton.OnClick := btnStartClick;
end;
```